# How to pass arguments to Hilt module?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I started to migrate Dagger application to Hilt, first I'm converting AppComponent to Hilt auto-generated ApplicationComponent. Therefore I've added `@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)` annotation to each module related to this component.

Now I get the following error:

> error: [Hilt] All modules must be static and use static provision
> methods or have a visible, no-arg constructor.

It points to this module:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
class AccountModule(private val versionName: String) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideComparableVersion(): ComparableVersion {
        return ComparableVersion(versionName)
    }
}
```

Previously in Dagger, it was possible to pass arguments in the constructor. Looks like Hilt doesn't allow this.

How can I pass arguments to Hilt module?

Comment: You can't pass as its using object instead of class there in modules.

Comment: @ShaluTD ok I see, thanks. Do you have any idea how to refactor the code to achieve the same with Hilt then?

Comment: You would need to create `versionName` inside the module instead of passing it in from outside.  How to do that depends on how you currently compute that value.

Comment: When do you plan to supply a different versionName? Is it in different build flavor?

Comment: Yes, it is in `BuildConfig`. Well I guess I can get it from there inside the module as suggested.

Comment: Actually I found in Dagger docs (https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/) that "@BindsInstance methods should be preferred to writing a @Module with constructor arguments and immediately providing those values." So I should probably first refactor the code to use this and then later migrate to Hilt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for now Dagger Hilt is design using monolithic component, where there's only one Application Component and one Activity Component auto generated by it. Refer to https://dagger.dev/hilt/monolithic.html

Hence the modules for it must be static and use static provision methods or have a visible, no-arg constructor.

If you put an argument to the module, it will error out stating

`[Hilt] All modules must be static and use static provision methods or have a visible, no-arg constructor.`

From my understanding, you'll trying to get the BuildInfo version number, perhaps the easiest way is to use the provided `BuildInfo.VERSION_NAME` as below.

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
class AccountModule() {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideComparableVersion(): ComparableVersion {
        return ComparableVersion(BuildInfo.VERSION_NAME)
    }
}
```

If you like to set it yourselves instead of relying on `BuildInfo.VERSION_NAME`, you can define static const variable that exist differently across flavour.

Answer (score 8):

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
class AccountModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideComparableVersion(application: Application): ComparableVersion {
        return ComparableVersion((application as MyApplication).versionName)
    }
}
```

If you don't want to see `MyApplication`, then you can use an interface.